# Angular 2 ngIf when function or click is executed

Tags: typescript, angular

How do I show an element only when a function or a specific click is executed? In my case this is my html markup:

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [mapTypeId]="maptype" [mapTypeControlOptions]="mapTypeControlOptions">
    <sebm-google-image-map-type [mapLayerId]="'linz'" [options]=imageMapOptions>
        <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="#location of locations" [latitude]="location.lat" [longitude]="location.lng" [label]="location.id" (markerClick)="updateDiv()">
            <sebm-google-map-info-window [disableAutoPan]="true"> {{ location.id }} <strong>{{ location.content }}</strong></sebm-google-map-info-window>
        </sebm-google-map-marker>
    </sebm-google-image-map-type>
</sebm-google-map>


<section  *ngIf="markerClick==true" id="ethiopian-desert">TEST</section>
```

I tried as you see with markerClick but it seems not to work. I want to show it when the marker is clicked and when clicked outside (somewhere on the screen) it has to close again.

Here a plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/djvrrBxov2Pq83DihC22?p=preview)

Comment: You should use `infoWindowClose` event for closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create and update a state and regarding of state value you will show or hide the section.
I created an example which will show the section when you click on the marker and hide it when you click on the map.

**In your template :**

```
  template: `
  <sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" (click)="hideSection($event)">
    <sebm-google-image-map-type [mapLayerId]="'linz'" [options]=imageMapOptions>
        <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="#location of locations" [latitude]="location.lat" [longitude]="location.lng" [label]="location.id" (markerClick)="showSection()">
            <sebm-google-map-info-window [disableAutoPan]="true"> {{ location.id }} <strong>{{ location.content }}</strong></sebm-google-map-info-window>
        </sebm-google-map-marker>
    </sebm-google-image-map-type>
</sebm-google-map>

  <section *ngIf="shouldDisplaySection" id="ethiopian-desert">TEST</section>
`
```

**In your component :**

```
  hideSection($event) {
    // stop event propagation on children
    $event.stopPropagation();

    this.shouldDisplaySection = false;
  }

  showSection() {
    this.shouldDisplaySection = true;
  }
```

The update plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/baF1WH1Dxp4eBAGpyHK6?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can bind your `*ngIf` expression to a boolean property that you toggle on click.

```
(markerClick)="updateDiv()"
<section *ngIf="isClicked" id="ethiopian-desert">TEST</section>
```

And in your App class

```
updateDiv() {
    this.isClicked = true;
}
```

See [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XvGkEodGUFU1qxpNY5hL?p=preview).

To hide the div, simply re-toggle the `this.isClicked` boolean property from the top-level element with another click event:

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" (click)="hideDiv()">
```

App:

```
hideDiv() {
    this.isClicked = false;
}
```